# Azure Redis Cache: "SocketClosed on PING" error

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

Running a test console app to connect to an Azure Redis Cache, it suddenly (without any changes to either client or server) stopped allowing me to connect with a "SocketClosed on PING" error.

Here are the logs from the connection attempt:

> [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=*****,ssl=True,abortConnect=False
>
> Connecting [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive...
>   BeginConnect: [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 1 unique nodes
>   specified Requesting tie-break from
>   [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
>   Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond... Awaiting task completion,
>   IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=0,Free=1023,Min=4,Max=1023) EndConnect:
>   [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 Configuring SSL Connected
>   Interactive/[redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 Server handshake
>   Authenticating (password) Setting client name: [redacted]
>   Auto-configure... Sending critical tracer:
>   Interactive/[redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 Writing to
>   Interactive/[redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: ECHO Flushing
>   outbound buffer Starting read Connect complete:
>   [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 All tasks completed cleanly,
>   IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
>   (Busy=2,Free=1021,Min=4,Max=1023)
>   [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: SocketClosed on PING
>   All tasks are already complete [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380
>   failed to nominate (Faulted)
>
> > UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET No masters detected [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v3.0.0, master;
> >     keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use:
> >     DidNotRespond [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=9,
> >     qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=10, socks=2; sub ops=4, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0,
> >     wr=0, sync=4, socks=2 Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0+9=9 (0.90
> >     ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+4=4 (0.40 ops/s; spans 10s) Sync timeouts:
> >     0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago resetting failing
> >     connections to retry... retrying; attempts left: 2... 1 unique nodes
> >     specified Requesting tie-break from
> >     [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
> >     Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond... Awaiting task completion,
> >     IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
> >     (Busy=4,Free=1019,Min=4,Max=1023) All tasks completed cleanly, IOCP:
> >     (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
> >     (Busy=2,Free=1021,Min=4,Max=1023)
> >     [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: SocketClosed on PING
> >     All tasks are already complete [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380
> >     failed to nominate (Faulted)
> >     UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET No masters detected [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v3.0.0, master;
> >     keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: Disconnected; not in
> >     use: DidNotRespond [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int
> >     ops=18, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=20, async=1, socks=3; sub ops=12,
> >     qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=12, socks=3 Circular op-count snapshot;
> >     int: 0+18=18 (1.80 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+12=12 (1.20 ops/s; spans
> >     10s) Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
> >     resetting failing connections to retry... retrying; attempts left:
> >     1... 1 unique nodes specified Requesting tie-break from [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
> >     Allowing endpoints 00:00:05 to respond... Awaiting task completion,
> >     IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
> >     (Busy=3,Free=1020,Min=4,Max=1023) All tasks completed cleanly, IOCP:
> >     (Busy=1,Free=999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER:
> >     (Busy=2,Free=1021,Min=4,Max=1023)
> >     [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: SocketClosed on PING
> >     All tasks are already complete [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380
> >     failed to nominate (Faulted)
> >     UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on GET No masters detected [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v3.0.0, master;
> >     keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Disconnected; sub: ConnectedEstablishing;
> >     not in use: DidNotRespond [redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int
> >     ops=27, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, sync=30, async=2, socks=4; sub ops=16,
> >     qu=0, qs=4, qc=0, wr=0, sync=12, socks=4 Circular op-count snapshot;
> >     int: 0+27=27 (2.70 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+16=16 (1.60 ops/s; spans
> >     10s) Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
> >     Starting heartbeat...

I'm using the StackExchange.Redis nuget package (version 1.1.608) and I'm connecting as follows:

```
var db = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("[redacted].redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=[redacted],ssl=True,abortConnect=False",sw)
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that I was not disconnecting my clients and I ran out of available connections:

[image]